# Mejorar mostrado de resultados de un select con LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Si yo realizo una consulta del tipo:

```
SELECT nombre FROM tabla WHERE nombre LIKE '%foo%'
```

Cómo podría ordenar / filtrar el resultado de manera que, por ejemplo, se muestren primero los resultados que más concuerdan con "`foo`"?

Por ejemplo, si tuviera: 
"`foo`", 
"`foooooooooo`", y 
"`342457fooooooooooooooo38407632069`"

cómo puedo hacer la consulta para que primero se muestre "`foo`"? (Debido a que es el resultado más próximo a lo que he pasado como entrada)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende de lo que quieras considerar como resultados que más concuerdan con tu cadena, puedes buscar diferentes métodos para calcular esa concordancia o distancia entre las palabras. El más sencillo sería comprobar la longitud de las cadenas y ordenar de menor a mayor, así los valores exactos aparecerán primero:

```
SELECT nombre 
FROM   tabla 
WHERE  nombre like "%foo%" 
ORDER BY (LENGTH(nombre) - LENGTH("foo"))
```

Y a partir de ahí lo podrías complicar todo lo que quieras: comprobando el número de apariciones de la palabra en la cadena, comparando la posición de la primera aparición, calculando la [distancia de Levenshtein](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distancia_de_Levenshtein)...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad! Era justo lo que necesitaba!!